# How to put the data in to 3 different categories

Tags: sql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I built a form where user enter their Product and Cost and this two pieces of information going to add in 3 different categories (Manufacturer, Manufacturing date and Expire date). There are total 20 different categories but users atleast enter information of 1 category and maximum 3 categories at a time. 
I don't know how to create the table where 2 pieces of information going to add in three different categories at once.

My idea is to make a parent table of 2 columns name Product and Cost, then make additional 20 tables for different categories but i don't know how the product and cost adds into these tables or how to interconnect each other .? 
Another method is to create 20 columns and then add multiple columns in a single columns which i don't know how to do that .?

Is this a good approach or is there any other way to make an efficient database based on these requirements. I am new to sql database. Any Idea how to do this .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very psuedo coded...20 table is pretty horrible to maintain.

**Table Product:**

ProductID

ProductName

Cost

**Table Category**

categoryID

categoryname

**Table Product_category**

ProductID

CategoryID

This will allow you to link a single product to an unlimited number of categories. 1 product to many product_categories to 1 category.

Comment: This is nice but how to add productID into three different categoryID at once ?

Comment: 1 entry in product...we will say productID 1.   3 entrees in product category...For example,  productID = 1 categoryID = 5.  ProductID = 1 categoryID = 43.  ProductID = 1 categoryID = 9.    This gives you 1 product related to 3 categories and allows for as many as you categories as you could want.  I recommend reading on a relational database and what a 1 to many relation is.

Comment: I got it .. Thanks

Comment: [_Tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on efficient schema for many:many mapping.